# how to automate ssh login where 2 passwords is required for user with perl script

Tags: perl, authentication, ssh, automation, passwords

I need to automate a test case where user,on ssh login, is prompted for 2nd password if user is authenticated successfully with 1st password (which is keyboard interactive).

How to automate this test case using perl ?

Have tried using perl SSH expect module but it only works for 1st password :

Without Enter your EMERG one-time password line, script works for single password. But if I include 2nd password ie. Enter your EMERG one-time password , following error is seen on compilation :

syntax error at test_pswrd.pl line 8, near "time password"
Global symbol "$ssh" requires explicit package name at test_pswrd.pl line 13. Execution of test_pswrd.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (host => "1.1.1.1",
password=> 'testpwd',
Enter your EMERG one-time password => '123456',
user => 'testuser',
raw_pty => 1);

my $login_output = $ssh->login();
print $login_output;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @AbhiNickz Have edited the question with perl module tried, but not sure if that's the correct way. Could you please help ?

Comment: Code you have entered here has no syntax error, it works and ssh to host successfully, So check your code, You have syntax error on your original code.

Comment: Have un-commented line "Enter your EMERG one-time password => '123456',"  in the shared code to enter 2nd password. please check now.

Comment: use quote around `'Enter your EMERG one-time password' => '123456',` like this and check if this removes your syntax error.

Comment: Unfortunately, quote ddnt helped. Error seen now is:    IllegalArgument attribute 'Enter your EMERG one-time password' is not a valid constructor argument. at test_pswrd.pl line 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165878/discussion-between-abhinickz-and-pooja).

Comment: Hello @Pooja, SSH-keys could save you of a lot of trouble in connecting. A solution like that would work for you or it is mandatory for you to connect through password?

Comment: I think that's what ssh keygen is for, with keys in your ~/.ssh dir.  Saving passwords in a script or otherwise may violate your company's security guidelines and is poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no SSH Perl module supports logging with more than one password directly.

[Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) allows one to use a custom [login handler](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#login_handler-=%3E-%5C&custom_login_handler), but you have to write the code to read the remote prompts and send the passwords at the right time.

Another option is to use [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect).

Which option is best depends on what you plan to do afterwards, once the connection is established. For complex SSH interactions, `Net::OpenSSH` is a better option. On the other hand, if you just want to send a single command to the remote side, probably writing the custom `login_handler` would not worth the trouble, so my advice would be to use `Expect` in that case.